# mtd_stresstest does not show any output and runs for ever even with count=1

Tags: linux, flash, filesystems, driver

I am using a rockchip 3188 based system on board which has 8 gb NAND flash.
I want to test the reliability of the NAND flash. 
At least , I want to identify boards with bad NAND flashes shipping from factory.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
The NAND flash is partitioned into two parts :
1. mtd0: contains bootloader, kernel and initrd
2. mtd1: contains RFS

I tried running mtd_stresstest by "modprobe mtd_stresstest dev=1" and it never says a word. If I run it for too long, my system is getting corrupted. The corruption is expected as it is playing with the same device / is mounted on.
But the command is not returning even if I use count=1.
Please let me know what is going wrong.

I tried the following too:

1. Flashed a USB stick with ubuntu rfs meant for arm and plugged it to SOB.
2. bind mounted /proc to /media//proc
3. bind mounted /sys to /media/

   cd /media/

   chroot .

   init 1

   modprobe mtd_stresstest dev=1 count=1 ----> never says a word

Could you please also suggest if there is any other way test the NAND flash device reliability.

Comment: I vote to migrate this to Super User since it is a pure hardware problem.

Comment: I want to test hardware but my problem is with mtd_stresstest kernel module.